# Как сделать, что-бы мой код работал не только при обновлении страницы?

Tags: javascript

С помощью кода удаляю класс? Код работает только при обновлении страницы. Как заставить его работать если я перешёл на другую страницу, а потом вернулся на ту где этот класс появляется?

```
 window.onload = function() {
     document.querySelector('span[class="com-chat-item-date d-n"]').classList.remove("d-n");
    };
```

Сделал так и этот код работает как мне нужно. Но грамотно ли он реализован?
В консоли браузера у меня каждую секунду пишет: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null (line 3)

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
 document.querySelector('span[class="com-chat-item-date d-n"]').classList.remove("d-n");
 observer.disconnect();
  });
});
mutationObserver.observe(document.documentElement, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
});
```

Comment: Привязать на нужное событие

Comment: @Maneken, что-то мне ваш ответ не особо помог)

Comment: использовать событие popstate ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский. почитал, ничего особо не понял. Сделал вот так:                                              
`var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {   mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {  document.querySelector('span[class="com-chat-item-date d-n"]').classList.remove("d-n");  observer.disconnect();   }); }); mutationObserver.observe(document.documentElement, {   childList: true,   subtree: true, });`  
   Код работает как надо, но правильно ли он сделан?

Comment: Что вкладывается в понятие "правильно"?

Comment: *"почитал, ничего особо не понял."* --- что именно не понятно? Тогда русскую версию открой)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, правильно ли он реализован. Работать то он работает. Но мало-ли в нём что-то не хватает или, что-то лишнее. Почему в консоле браузера выдает ошибку с интервалом в 1 секунду. Значит код работает постоянно, Почему не отключается. Значит в коде чего-то не хватае. Не хватает видимо того, что его должно отключить, когда на странице нет класса 
`com-chat-item-date d-n` и наоборот он должен запустится когда на странице есть `com-chat-item-date d-n`. Я правильно рассуждаю?

Comment: В ошибке написано, что нет такого класса, нечего удалять. Попробуй реализовать через if. Если такой класс есть - удалить. И это не ответы, а просто комментарии. Вопрос не сильно понятен, вот и ответов четких нет